# Mixed Content: The page at 'https://***********.web.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://ec2-/-/-/-/-/-'

Tags: reactjs, amazon-ec2, aws-amplify, firebase-hosting, react-fullstack

> I have hosted one of my react app on Google Firebase which is by
> default HTTPS and one of my react app is hosted on AWS amplify which
> is also by default HTTTPS and the backend is hosted on aws-ec2 which
> is HTTP.

> Is there any way that without upgrading my aws-ec2 to HTTPS I can use the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use no http resource with firebase hosting, also you can't convert firebase hosting site to http. So, i suggest you to find another way to fix this.

- Stop using firebase, and find another host where http resources is allowed.
- Change you backend to https. There's an easy way to do this using a letsencrypt certificate. To generate the certificate, I recommend you use acme-nginx client https://github.com/kshcherban/acme-nginx.